# Extract images with xpath and scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to get images from this website https://www.milieuproperties.com/For-Sale/western-cape/durbanville/ and I am having issues with getting all the images of the property; more specifically extracting the URL of images.

this is how the code I have for now looks like but I always get an empty array:

```
images = response.xpath('//*[@class="slick-track"]/div/img/@src').getall()
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Loading that URL gives me a server error, so you'll have to [pay attention to the MCVE section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the how to ask page. The tl;dr of almost any answer is going to be: "do you see `slick-track` in the _view source_ for that page, because if not, the Scrapy is not going to see it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mdaniel said, the xpath you're using works when the page is rendered, but scrapy cannot see it. You can check what scrapy sees using `scrapy shell "$URL"`, and doing `view(response)`.
You can also look for the image-urls in the page-source. The following xpath seems to do the trick:

```
images = response.xpath('//*[@class="MyImage"]//*[has-class("slider-nav")]//@src').extract()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works like a charm, helpful info to use view(response)! @WimHermans